# C++ Implicitly returning return type variable

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-warnings

I noticed this when I realized I had forgotten a return statement in a function, but I was still getting the value as expected. So I tried to recreate the situation in a simple program and it did the same thing -- returned the expected value without an explicit return statement.

I've noticed it doesn't work if I change the printf format specifier type from `f` to `d` for example. Or if I create a variable called `double tau = 6.2830`, but having multiple variable of the return type causes the last variable defined to be returned.

So my conclusion is that this is the work of the compiler to correct my mistake, but this doesn't seem very helpful and I would expect this to be an error rather than a warning hidden besides when using `-Wall` or some other related flag.

Is my conclusion correct and what is the reasoning behind this design decision?

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                              

float pi() {                                                                                                                           
    float pi = 3.1415;
    // float tau = 6.2830;    // this will now return instead
    // double cthulhu = -000000.000000011101; // this will not allow it to work                                                      
}                                                                               

int main() {                                                                    
    float num;                                                                  
    num = pi();                                                                 
    printf("Some number is %f", num);       // changing %f to %d will also not allow it to work                                    
    return 0;                                                                   
}
```

Compiled with

```
g++ test.cpp -o test
```

Output

```
$ ./test
Some number is 3.141500
```

Compiler output with the -Wall flag

```
a.cpp: In function ‘float pi()’:
a.cpp:4:11: warning: unused variable ‘pi’ [-Wunused-variable]
     float pi = 3.1415;
           ^~
a.cpp:5:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
 }
```

Comment: You are missing a `return` statement at all!

Comment: TL;DR on the dupe: It's undefined. In your case it probably just so happens to be picking up the last value on the stack or something.

Comment: @JasonC Unfortunately I can't hammer using your dupe anymore. I've been close voting for other reasons too early. I don't get why this question is upvoted so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function doesn't have a `return` statement (that's what the compiler warning is telling you clearly), and there's no such thing like an *implicitely returned* type or variable. You have undefined behavior with that function, digest it.

To fix use something like

```
float pi() {                                                                
    return 3.1415f;
}
```

or a simple declaration like

```
constexpr float pi = 3.1415f;
```